# Slave servers KETTLE pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am using Carte web server to execute transformations remotly, somtimes when the web service called multiple times at the same moment I got a timeout then an error with description "GC overhead limit exceeded".

I want to know Why I am getting this issue, and should creating multiple slave servers be the solution, if so what is the procedure?

NOTE: https://xxxx/kettle/getSlaves return :

```
<SlaveServerDetections></SlaveServerDetections>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer

```
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

is about you carte server is run out of memory. Carte server is just a jetty server with PDI functionality, it is java process by it's nature wich is run jobs or transformations. Jobs and transformations by it's nature just a description of what carte server should do. Fetch some data, sort string, anything that have been configured. If you want to run massive tasks of Carte server you have to tune Carte startup script to give to java process more memory, more heap space, define best GC strategy or what ever based on your knowledge on what is exactly have to be tuned. Just try to google on 'GC overhead limit exceeded' and play with java process startup arguments.

When server returns

```
<SlaveServerDetections></SlaveServerDetections>
```

I is just says it is did not find any slaves (most probably you carte server is a alone master). It is not related to a GC overhead.